# Customizing map layers in Esri Javascript

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, html5

I'm working on creating an outdoors-app-thingy where I'm required to divide up parts of 3 different rivers where the app is focused around into different "zones".

After a lot of calling around and searching, I came across ArcGIS/ESRI which has everything that I need and it's a lot more detailed than anything else out there, and have been playing around with it for a few days now.

I was wondering if it's possible to add something similar to click events to the Areas that I'm adding to the map?

The thought behind it is that the page you navigate to the map from transmits the data that sets the map center and zoom, depending on which river you selected on the previous page you have 1 to 3 "areas" that are drawn on the map.

When clicking one of these "Areas", jQuery would simply just direct you to the final view where you'd get more streamlined information.

Would something like this even be possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes. definitely possible. check out this sample which demonstrates how to pull out url parameters and manipulate the map.

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jssamples/exp_history.html

Comment: Thank you for that link! That's really awesome.   I was looking around the 4.0 documentation for hours without being able to find something remotely close to what I needed.  Do you know if this is only available to v3.16 as of now?

Comment: we don't have 4.x samples yet, but urlUtils are definitely available there too. https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-core-urlUtils.html